# Parse Selenium WebElement Libraries?

Tags: python, selenium

I have a test which is sending thousands of api requests in order to complete the test. This is causing the test to take a very long time to complete, over 15 minutes.

What I am doing over and over again is find an element, then I find two elements within that element and then I read the text of those elements.

This causes selenium to send an api request for the element and then another to find the elements within the element, and then one final one to get the text of the element. I could skip all of these api requests if I just did one request to get the DOM tree of the first element then parse the HTML for the text of the elements. Is there a library used for this purpose.

Something along the lines of this?

```
Import ElementParser

elems = map(ElementParser, driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div.row'))

for elem in elems:
  name = elem.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div.content').text
  description = elem.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR. 'div.description').text
```

It would be great if this library uses a WebElement as an argument and mimics selenium syntax as shown above. If nothing like this exists then I could create my own Library but I'd rather use something that already exists.

I'm new to stackoverflow so hopefully random advice questions like this is appropriate.

Comment: you should be able to put the logic into a single locator.  So your find elements method finds all cells you want instead of rows.  ex: xpath of "//div[contains(@class, "description")]   Then iterate and call .text method on each to get your results.

Comment: That's a good suggestion but doesn't directly correlate to my situation since not all rows have descriptions and I have to determine which one's have descriptions and which ones do not.

Comment: I've never used it but I think Beautiful Soup is what you're looking for: https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/

Comment: Hey! That could work, thanks mate.

Comment: My QA spidey sense is tingling... while your example code isn't the most efficient I wouldn't expect such a huge time sink out of that.   Granted I can't see what you're looking at, but still.   How certain are you that _this_ is the root cause of your slowness?

Answer (score 0):

BeautifulSoup was the exact sort of library I was looking for. I was easily able to override one of my functions to use BeautifulSoup instead of selenium. This caused nearly a 100x speed increase since it would no longer need to wait for API responses.

Original function:

```
  def find_value(self, cell):
    text = self.find_element(*self.get_row_selector(cell.cell_number)).get_attribute('innerHTML')
    if text:
      return text
```

New Function:

```
  def find_value(self, cell):
    text = BeautifulSoup(self.get_attribute('innerHTML'), 'html.parser').select(self.get_row_selector(cell.cell_number)[1])[0].decode_contents()
    if text:
      return text
```

(Code not copied verbatim to make more readable. Also type(self) == WebElement)